# What is performance difference between using ALL vs REMOVEFILTERS?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm thinking of using either of the below to remove a filter via the CALCULATE DAX.

What is the performance difference between using `ALL(table)` vs `ALL(table[col])` vs `REMOVEFILTERS(table)` vs `REMOVEFILTERS(table[col])`

Comment: There is no difference. Removefilters is just an alias (syntax sugar).

Comment: And how about removing filter from table versus column. Is there any differences between these 2 generally?